# knockout Call function for each item

Tags: function, text, knockout.js, foreach

I have this :

```
function viewModel() {
        this.items = ko.observableArray(initialData);
    }

ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

...and this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:  items">
 <span data-bind="text: cutOff($data)"></span>
</div>
```

Question: I have multiple columns. For the comment column I need a function that for each item shows a substring of the first 40 characters and: (...) 
to show that the text has been cut off.
I have tried this with a computed function.. No luck.

I need something like this :

```
var cutOff= function (fieldName) {
            if (fieldName.Length > 40)
                return fieldName.substring(0, 40) + "(...)"
            else
                return fieldName;
}
```

The proper syntax is still a mystery to me. Can this be done anyway?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to create a custom binding that returns a cutOff version of the text. This way you will be able to re-use it anywhere you need to cutOff your text.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.trimText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var trimmedText = ko.computed(function () {
            var ActualText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var defaultMaxLength = 20;
            var minTrimLength = 5;
            var maxTrimLength = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().trimLength) || defaultMaxLength;
            if (maxTrimLength < minTrimLength) maxTrimLength = minTrimLength;
            var textOutput = ActualText.length > maxTrimLength ? ActualText.substring(0, maxTrimLength - 1) + '(...)' : ActualText;
            return textOutput;
        });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { text: trimmedText }, viewModel);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    }
};
```

View :

```
<!-- default cutOff length -->
<div data-bind="trimText: ItemText"></div> 
<!-- cutOff length -->
<div data-bind="trimText: ItemText, trimLength: 40"></div>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/143/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cutOff function is defined inside the viewModel like shown below.

```
function viewModel() {
        this.items = ko.observableArray(initialData);

        this.cutOff= function (fieldName) {
            if (fieldName.Length > 40)
                return fieldName.substring(0, 40) + "(...)"
            else
                return fieldName;

         }

    }
```

You need to access the cutOff function through the `$parent` **bindingContext**. So, in HTML page, code should be like. In `foreach` loop, the binding context for the span element would be the individual item or the `$data`. If you need to access the functions defined at your ViewModel then you need to change the binding context and `$parent` allows to access the parent Context.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:  items">
 <span data-bind="text: $parent.cutOff($data)"></span>
</div>
```

**Update:** The reason it is giving an undefined error is because you are not creating an instance of the viewModel. If you are not creating an instance the viewModel function, calling viewModel(), return undefined and undefined doesn't contain any method like cutOff.

So, you need to replace the code like shown below and then it should work.

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: - function cutOff  not defined

Comment: I see the problem with your code. Updated the answer to ensure that your code works.

Comment: Im trying to cut off CH_Nom

Comment: Updated your fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/yorxoj3r/1/. Please note the mistake is that you are forgetting the `new` in 'new viewModel' while applyin the `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());`